# How to show dhcp server's ip address for every VLAN on cisco switch?

Tags: dhcp, switch, ip-address

Is there a way on Cisco layer 3 switches to show the DHCP server's IP address for every VLAN?

Comment: Do you mean the helper addresses?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how helper addresses relate to the DHCP server's IP address.

Comment: A helper address is the IP address of the DHCP server. Placing the `ip helper-address <dhcp server address>` command on the VLAN interfaces enables DHCP relay and will allow DHCP to function on a VLAN on which there is no DHCP server connected. Other than that, hosts find a DHCP server via a layer-2 broadcast so the IP address doesn't really matter because the host can't contact the DHCP server via IP address since the host doesn't have an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

If the dhcp server is running on the switch itself, then it should be visible in the running config and you can likely visually look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question but I think I've found what you're looking for. It's called **DHCP Snooping**. On a switch you can configure DHCP snooping like this:

1. Enable DHCP snooping on your switch:

`Switch(config)#ip dhcp snooping`

2. Specify which VLAN DHCP snooping should be applied to:

`Switch(config)#ip dhcp snooping vlan 1-3`

3. Enable DHCP snooping on the interface linked to your DHCP server:

`Switch(config-if)#ip dhcp snooping trust`

4. This command will show you Mac Address, Ip Address, Lease(sec), Type, VLAN and interface of a DHCP client.

`Show ip dhcp snooping binding`

I hope this helped, good luck :)